# How to use ProgressBar Control with DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, progress-bar

I want to use a `ProgressBar` control in C# when my `DataGridView` is loading data, but when I run my program I get an error:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'dataGridView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Code:

```
private readonly BackgroundWorker _bw = new BackgroundWorker();

public workerbloks()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 30;

    // set Visible false before you start long running task
    progressBar1.Visible = false;
    _bw.DoWork += show_worked_bloks;
    _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += BW_RunWorkerCompleted;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Show();
    _bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void BW_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Hide();
}

public void show_worked_bloks(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
{
    MYDBMS md = new MYDBMS();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    clsWorkBloks clswb = new clsWorkBloks();

    try
    {
        dt = md.ExecuteSelectSQL(clswb.show_all_worked_bloks());
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `BeginInvoke` or `dataGridView1.Invoke` for DataGridView1

Comment: can you verify my code with invoke object?

Comment: Have you tried given answer?

Comment: Look up the walkthrough on background worker on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx); note espcially the  reportprogress function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the specified delegate asynchronously on the thread that the `dataGridView1` underlying handle was created on.

```
dataGridView1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
});
```

As the progressbar is just marquee display. Simply bring it to front before running background worker.

```
progressBar1.BringToFront();
progressBar1.Show();
_bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```